# In MATLAB, how can I declare an implicit variable, y(t), after I have used it in a symbolically defined function?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm writing a scheme that solves an ODE and in doing so I declare a symbolic function:

```
syms t y(t) 
f = t^(-2) * (sin(2*t) - 2*t*y)
```

At one point I have to take a total derivative, so I need `y(t)` to be be implicit in the expression, but I also need to evaluate `f(t,y)` at a specific value of `t` and `y`. I attempt to do this in the following lines.

```
y(t) = wi;
out(1) = f(ti);
```

However, I am prompted with the following error.

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double: 
Unable to convert expression containing remaining symbolic function calls into double array. 
Argument must be expression that evaluates to number.
```

```
Error in DiffEq_alt (line 13)
out(1) = f(ti);
```

Ultimately, I need to be able to be able to declare `y` explicitly, but also treat it implicitly for when I differentiate the function `f(t,y(t))` with respect to `t`.

Note: This exact question was also posted on MathWorks.

Comment: If you have not solved this problem, can you provide simple code that can replicate your issue and error?